# Available Servlet 3.0 implementations?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, containers

Which implementations of the Servlet 3.0 specification are available (or at least in beta) besides GlassFish?

Comment: as of 2010-06-15 there is no other production ready servlet 3.0 than GlassFish 3.0

Answer (score 10):

Tomcat 7.0 is [on its way](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9a2ae02474ebdd29990f034e05f8ebcd1789552d/TOMCAT-7-RELEASE-PLAN.txt). It is still in development. Jetty 8 is supposed to implement Servlet 3.0, it is also [still in development](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/about.php) (check the *Versions* section at bottom).

As far now there's only the [GlassFish v3](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/downloads/v3-final.html) as being a stable release.

Comment: In fact I think GlassFish is just using Tomcat: jar tf glassfish/modules/web-core.jar shows org.apache.catalina and org.apache.tomcat classes.

Comment: @Mirko: Glassfish uses a forked version of Tomcat

Comment: In January 2011, the first stable version (7.0.6) has been released

Answer (score 2):

There is [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/about.php)

Comment: Note that you'd need Jetty 8.x which is still Experimental.

Comment: I can confirm that: Jetty 7 supports only parts of Servlet 3.0. You cannot deploy a .war file without a web.xml for example.

Comment: Yes, maybe I was somewhat too fast with Jetty :) still have to wait some more. shame on me :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd also mention [Resin 4.0](http://caucho.com/resin/doc/index.xtp), in development.