# Application server with servlet 3.0 support..?

Tags: web-services, jsp, web-applications, servlets, servlet-3.0

I need an Application server with Servlet 3.0 support..

Currently I am working on Tomcat but I need to know some other application servers which support Servlet 3.0..

Please help me if known

Comment: possible duplicate of [Available Servlet 3.0 implementations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979473/available-servlet-3-0-implementations)

Comment: Possibly, but the information in the answers there is very out-of-date.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is not an application server, just merely a servlet container. You can try GlassFish.

Answer (score 0):

[Jboss Application Server 7](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas.html) have support for  Servlet 3.0.  and [Few more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979473/available-servlet-3-0-implementations) are there